# Controlled Inputs, displayed values will not update to last digit

Tags: reactjs

i'm using React(Typescript Version) to display some input inside a form.
The problem (as you can see from the image) is that when i update the values, from the setState function, values will not 'scroll' on the right

[image: Trying to update values]

```
render() {
 return(
   <input
   name={this.props.input.Name}
   type={this.props.input.Type}
   defaultValue={this.state.value}
   ref={this._input}
   key={key()}
)}
```

The function that updates the Value is a common set Function :

```
public set Value(data: string) {
  this.setState({
   internalValue: data,
   inputError: !this.validateValue(data)
  });
}
```

Note that the input works as expected if i write from the Keyboard, but if i write the input using a 'simulated' keyboard on screen happens what i just described

Any ideas?

Thank you

Update after simbathesailor support:

```
render() {
     return(
       <input
       name={this.props.input.Name}
       type={this.props.input.Type}
       defaultValue={this.state.value}
       ref={this._input}
       key={key()}
       onChange={this.setValue}
     />
    )
}


componentDidUpdate(prevProps: InputProps, prevState: InputState) {
        if (prevState.value!== this.state.value) {
            this._input.current.focus();
        }
    }

setValue(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    console.log('change');
    this.setState({
        value: event.target.value
    })
}

shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps: InputProps, nextState: InputState): boolean {
        return (this.state.value!= nextState.value);
    }


public set Value(data: string) {

        this.setState({
            value: data,
            inputError: !this.validateValue(data)
        }, () => {
            this._input.current.focus();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you use `value` instead of `defaultValue`?

Comment: Yes, i'm using defaultValue just to compare it to keyboard's event movement :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the refs and commit lifecycle method componentDidUpdate method. to achieve this.
In the example mentioned below, it is done for the uncontrolled component. But idea will remain same for controlled component also.

```
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.InputRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {
      value: 0
    }
  }
  setValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      value:event.target.value
    })
  }
  update = () => {
    this.setState({
      value: (this.state.value || 0) + 1000
    })
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if(prevState.value !== this.state.value) {
      this.InputRef.current.focus()
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     <input 
       value={this.state.value}
       onChange={this.setValue}
       ref={this.InputRef}
      /> 
      <button onClick={this.update}>update</button>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

Here is the codepen link to see it working:

1. [Uncontrolled approach(javascript) codepen link](https://codepen.io/stack26/pen/VENXWy)
2. [Controlled approach(javascript) codepen link](https://codepen.io/stack26/pen/wYZmZV)

I have tried typescript for the first time. Thanks for your question :). Typescript is good. And here is your desired solution needed in typescript.

3. [Codesandbox link(Typescript)](https://codesandbox.io/s/5wz8wpov14)

Comment: Hi simbathesailor, thank you for the help. I've tried your solution but it seems not working for me. I've noticed that the 'onChange' event does not fire

Comment: Can you please update the latest code in question i will have a look in 5-10 minutes

Comment: onChange also need to be passed from props. You can see my controlled codepen example which i have pasted above in the answer. You need to pass refs , handler amnd value from props

Comment: I've updated the setValue function as you did, but can't get the Change Event

Comment: Is this typescript ?. Could you please give me the complete child component and parent component excluding the private code part

Comment: I dont know why jsfiddle refues to compile (my local compiler works fine) anyway this is the base code : https://jsfiddle.net/randomNameGenerator26/1b68eLdr/81134/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182737/discussion-between-simbathesailor-and-user3787626).

Comment: I've updated the Demo just to give a complete Example ;) https://codesandbox.io/s/2092x9yo3j